# Hide Product DropDown in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I am using an extension of the mageworx "Advanced Configurable Option ..." https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-advanced-product-options-suite.html

I could have used the basic magento configurable products, but unfortunately for the work I had to do I should have created more than a thousand attributes.

The extension support told me that it is an incompatibility with my theme, and I have to pay. But I like to solve problems alone and above all to understand how I solved it well. This is to enrich my experience.

"isWatched" It should hide the dropdown , but in my theme it doesn't work and the drop down remains.

[image]

The question is: is it possible to HIDE the dropdown only on the product page?
Can i do this with css?
[image]

URL Product : https://gyps.it/it/test-product.html

Magento CE 2.2.2

Thanks!